# Sapui5 load Data pass by parameter

Tags: sapui5

I am learning sapui5. I want pass my model data vitw parameter. I tried this but I think this is very bad a choice. How can I fix this?

```
var view = this.getView();
var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var variable="testVariable";
model.loadData("......format=json&key=selectbyname&Name=" +variable+ ");        
view.setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to build the URL as string

```
var variable = "testVariable";
var url = "http://www.example.org/models?type=json&name=" + variable;
model.loadData(url);        
view.setModel(model);
```

in your case it should be enough if you delete the bold part, so that you receive valid javascript:
`model.loadData("......format=json&key=selectbyname&Name=" +variable` **+ "**`);`

to
`model.loadData("......format=json&key=selectbyname&Name=" + variable );`